# Why can't I access object properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a simply loop in node.js:

```
exports.sample = function (req, res) {
    var images = req.query.images;
    images.forEach(function (img) {
        console.log(img);
        console.log(img.path, img.id);
        console.log(img);
    });
    res.end();
};
```

The result is:

```
{"id":42,"path":"gGGfNIMGFK95mxQ66SfAHtYm.jpg"}
undefined undefined
{"id":42,"path":"gGGfNIMGFK95mxQ66SfAHtYm.jpg"}
```

I can access the properties in the client side but not on the server side.

Can someone help me to understand what's happening? Why can't I access my object properties?

Comment: Just check whether it is `object` or `string`

Comment: [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it maybe ?

Comment: add `img = JSON.parse(img)` before logs

Comment: The above comments are most likely correct.  If `img` were an object then the console output would be more like `Object {id: 42, path: "gGGfNIMGFK95mxQ66SfAHtYm.jpg"}`.  What you've posted is a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, most probably `img` is in string form. You need to run `JSON.parse()` on it to convert it to an object, so you can access its properties.

Here I have written the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) inside a check i.e. only when `img` is of type "string" should you parse it. But I think, you will always be getting `img` as a string, so you can simply parse it without the check.

```
exports.sample = function (req, res) {
    var images = req.query.images;
    images.forEach(function (img) {
        console.log(img);

        //Here, this code parses the string as an object
        if( typeof img === "string" )
          img = JSON.parse( img );

        console.log(img.path, img.id);
        console.log(img);
    });
    res.end();
};
```

Comment: @belyid You were getting a string and not an object ( not arrays ) ;)

Comment: @belyid if you are working with express you should add body.parser as a middlware so you dont need to write this on every request.

Comment: In this case I was getting an array with only one string. But it could be more than one string that needed to be parsed.